# React Datepicker swap the day and month when user try to enter value manually

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

In datepicker you want to create dates in **DD/MMM/YYYY** format. It's okay when I make a selection using the calendar, but when the user tries to enter a value, it changes the day and month.

How do I resolve this issue? do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant DD/MM/YYYY. Haven't worked with react-datepicker but I'm pretty sure you should be able to modify date format options. If you did this already, then your onChange handler might be messing up the format. Can't really guide you without seeing the code.